# Angular ng-include issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So what am I doing wrong? I included the ng-include and tried every variation and it is not including the file(it keeps returning a 404 in the console), the directory location is as follows:

```
-App
--Layout
---Partials
----Navigation.tpl.html(File)
--Layout.tpl.html(File)
```

And the ng-include is located in the `layout.tpl.html` file:

```
<div data-ng-include="'layout/partials/Navigation.tpl.html'"></div>
```

Please note that I am using webpack for this project(that shouldn't matter). I am calling the `layout.tpl.html` file as the base layout, and the partials are included inside the `layout.tpl.html` file. Also, I am using vs having a ng-app on the DOM:

```
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
});
```

I have worked with angular in the past, and I am at a loss when such a simple task is taking so long time. Also note, when I use the

```
$templateCache.put('..','..')
```

and put in html minified string from the `navigation.tpl.html` with the same directory, it works just fine (but if I use `$templateCache.get()` or `require()` from the template location, it doesn't work), but the HTML string is pulling from the cache and I want to be able to update one file vs having to use minified code.

Sorry in advance if I missed something, I am in a rush to get this done, and it should be the simplest thing that is just not working.

Comment: Could you attach the error you are receiving with the complete (wrong) path to the file? Sometimes is a question of slashes

Comment: You are including `navigation.tpl.html` but on the top you mention the file is called `Nav.tpl.html`

Comment: Sorry, it is navigation.tpl.html.

Comment: dev.mywebsite.com:44944/layout/partials/navigation.tpl.html 404 (Not Found). And if I inspect the dom, I see the nginclude commented out... Never had this issue before. Think this could be a webpack issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader

You should preload your template with the correct key in the $templateCache by requiring it in your bundle.

```
require('ngtemplate?module=[xx]&relativeTo=/layout/partials/!./layout/partials/Navigation.tpl.html');
```

That way you can ask for 'Navigation.tpl.html' in `ng-include` or with `templateUrl`

Comment: That was it, you are a life savor!